# Why does array contain two instance properties named `indices`?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, range

In [swift's array documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array), I saw there are two instance properties named `indices`

[image]

This puzzles me a lot. Why does array contain two instance properties named `indices`? what is the distinction between the two? how can we and the code we write tell the difference between the two?

Comment: That looks like a bug in the (automatically generated?) documentation to me. The latter is the actual indices method of the Array type. The former is a default protocol extension method which is only relevant for types which do *not* define their own implementation.